# XAML ListBox displays class name instead of class property

Tags: xaml, windows-8

Here I have a Listbox configured where the TextBlox in the DataTemplate is set to bind the "Name" Property.  But instead it shows the full class name "DomainClasses.Entities.Program". Why?

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding _CurrentProgram }">
.....
.....
    <ListBox x:Name="ProgramsListBox" Width="600" Height="400" Margin="50,0,50,0" ItemsSource="{Binding _Programs}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
       <DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
----
----
</Grid>
```

This is the ViewModel class

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        _currentProgram = new Program();
        _Programs = new ObservableCollection<Program>();
    }

    public async void SaveProgram(bool isEditing)
    {
        _Programs.Add(_currentProgram);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

    private Program _currentProgram;
    public Program _CurrentProgram
    {
        get { return _currentProgram; }
        set
        {

            _currentProgram = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Program> _programs;
    public ObservableCollection<Program> _Programs
    {
        get
        {
            return _programs;
        }
        set
        {
            this._programs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're getting a list of `Program` in your listbox instead of a list of the names of the programs?

Comment: yes.  This exactly: "DomainClasses.Entities.Program"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Noticed the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` around the `DataTemplate`.

What you have:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ProgramsListBox" Width="600" Height="400" Margin="50,0,50,0" ItemsSource="{Binding _Programs}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
   <DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Creates a `ListBox` with a `DataTemplate` as a child (in the same sense that the items in the `ItemsSource` are children of the `ListBox`).  If I remember correctly, when you set the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox`, all items set in the other fashion are removed.  So what you're ending up with is a `ListBox` with a bunch of `Program`s in it, which no `ItemsTemplate` set, so it simply shows the name of the bound class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the data template inside listview.itemtemplate and then do the binding. Right now you are adding the data template as a child of the listview.